# Joining multiple lines based on a regex

Tags: awk, text-formatting

I have the output of a pandoc conversion to HTML which looks like this:

```
foo

bar

<blockquote>

That's one small step for man, one giant leap for mankind

A new line and another quote

</blockquote>

baz
```

I'd like to make it like this:

```
foo

bar<blockquote>That's one small step for man, one giant leap for mankind

A new line and another quote</blockquote>baz
```

(Because block quotes are rendered separately anyway so I don't need the extra new lines.)

I started trying with sed and ended up with this awk:

```
'/./ {printf "%s%s", $0, ($1 ~ /^$/ && $2 ~ /<\/?blockquote>/) ? OFS : ORS}'
```

Which does part of what I want, but is a bit too advanced for me to understand how to modify.

In words I think the rule I want is: if the next line is blank and the one after matches `/<\/?blockquote>/`, then print current line, next line, and the one after without any separators, and then move on.

Comment: Something tells me the `awk` shall not work on six lines of text only. If that is the case then please explain exactly how to handle the data.

Comment: There are tools for working with HTML and XML documents, but what you show is just a fragment which doesn't look like either HTML nor XML (the `foo` and `bar` can't be written like that; `foo` must be part of some other node, possibly a `p` node, while `bar` could be the value of the `body` node that you don't show, which, if this is HTML, ought to be part of a root `html` node).

Comment: @Kusalananda correct. This is after stripping out `<p>` tags. The full command I use to produce this is `pandoc file.org -t html | gsed 's:</\?p>::g' | gsed 's:$:\n:g'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a `Perl`'s one liner:

`>= 5.36`:

```
$ perl -gpe 's/(\w+)\n\n(</?blockquote\b[^\n]+)\s*\n/$1$2/g' file
```

Or `< 5.36`:

```
$ perl -0777 -pe 's/(\w+)\n\n(</?blockquote\b[^\n]+)\s*\n/$1$2/g' file
```

```
foo<blockquote>That's one small step for man, one giant leap for mankind

A new line and another quote</blockquote>bar
```

---

- `-g` or `-0777` read the whole file in memory
- `'s///'` is the replacement skeleton, exactly like `sed`
- `$1$2` are the two captured groups, like `\1\2` with `sed`

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `(` | group and capture to $1: |
| `\w+` | word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `)` | end of $1 |
| `\n` | '\n' (newline) |
| `\n` | '\n' (newline) |
| `(` | group and capture to $2: |
| `</?blockquote` | '<' + optional '/' + 'blockquote' |
| `\b` | word boundary anchor |
| `[^\n]+` | any character except: '\n' (newline) (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `)` | end of $2 |
| `\s*` | whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `\n` | '\n' (newline) |

Comment: Many thanks. Such a succinct and powerful command! To fit my exact input I altered the first capturing group to `(\S+:?\.?)`

Answer (score 3):

Using GNU awk for multi-char `RS`, `RT`, `gensub()`, and `\s` and without reading the whole file into memory at one time:

```
$ awk -v RS='\\s*</?blockquote>\\s*' '{ORS=gensub(/\s+/,"","g",RT)} 1' file
foo

bar<blockquote>That's one small step for man, one giant leap for mankind

A new line and another quote</blockquote>baz
```

Comment: Wow, that is some black belt awk! It didn't work with my system (macOS) awk, but with GNU awk (installed via homebrew) it is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'BEGIN { waiting_for_tag=1; };
     NF==0 { next; };
     $1 ~ "</?blockquote>" { printf "%s",$1; waiting_for_tag=0; next; };
     waiting_for_tag==1 { printf "%s",$0; next; }; 
     { printf "%s\n",$0; waiting_for_tag=1; }' input
foo<blockquote>That's one small step for man, one giant leap for mankind
A new line and another quote</blockquote>bar
```

Comment: Thanks, this works really well except that it also strips blank lines not adjacent to a `<blockquote>` tag (for example, after "mankind").

Comment: @joshFriedlander: All you need to do is to modify HaukeLaging's answer adding a new line(`\n`) in the last `printf` block:  `{ printf "%s\n\n",$0;...}`.

Comment: @Cbhihe no, the `NF==0 { next; }` would still strip all blank lines and the other `printf`s would need some work too even if you did that.

Comment: @EdMorton, yes, `NF==0 {next}` strips blank lines by not printing them, hence the suggested `{ printf "%s\n\n",$0;...}` would print two newlines to compensate, but only for any 2nd citation following `</?blockquote>`. ---
 Anyway we all agree that this solution is far from optimal, being ultra-specialized to a particular example format and length. 
Yours is more general (and arguably  more readable) as it does not touch anything that is between the first and last non empty records located inside `\\s*</?blockquote>\\s*`.